# how to get selected value from Drop-down, if drop-down is binded with keys of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I am very new to Angularjs, I have binded column names(keys from key value pair) to the select list and want to get the key name on change of selection of select.
Select list is showing:

name, snippet and age

And on selection change i want the selected text of select. Please help
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div ng-controller="HelloController">

    <h2>Hello {{helloTo.title}} !</h2>
    <select ng-options="key for (key,val) in phones[0]" ng-change="ChangeValue(key)" ng-model="phones"></select>
</div>


<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
        .controller("HelloController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.helloTo = {};
            $scope.helloTo.title = "World, AngularJS";
            $scope.phones = [
                {
                    'name': 'Nexus S',
                    'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
                    'age': 1
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
                    'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
                    'age': 2
                },
                {
                    'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
                    'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
                    'age': 3
                }
            ];
            $scope.ChangeValue = function (selectedval) {

                alert(selectedval.name);
            };
        });
</script>
```

Comment: im not very expert with angular but if you console selectedVal what does it output ?

Comment: It return undefined as a value

Comment: and does the alert work , i mean does the ChangeValue method fire?

Comment: Why are you using (key,value)? Btw., I feel like you are using it wrong. Do you really want to show name, snippet, age in your select?

Comment: @s.alem : yes I want to show the column name and then i want to concatenate all values for the selected column on selection change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-options="key as key for (key,value) in phones[0]" ng-change="ChangeValue()" ng-model="selectedVal"></select>
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module("myapp", [])
        .controller("HelloController", function ($scope) {
$scope.helloTo = {};
  $scope.helloTo.title = "World, AngularJS";
  $scope.selectedVal = '';
  $scope.phones = [{
    'name': 'Nexus S',
    'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
    'age': 1
  }, {
    'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
    'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
    'age': 2
  }, {
    'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
    'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
    'age': 3
  }];
  $scope.ChangeValue = function() {

    console.log($scope.selectedVal);
  };
});
```

It's right in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) actually...

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ic2p99aXPoWgFtVW8LEU?p=preview).

Comment: Actually my dropdown show the column name not the value like "name, snippet and age" and once i click on any item i want this column name not the name/snippet/Age of the phone. so please update your answer

Comment: Check my edit. Is this what you want or I misunderstood?

Comment: Partially correct, once i select "name", it log "Nexus S" where as i want "name" itself. Could you please update.

Comment: could you please let me know how to set selected value of this dropdown?